# How to write a custom kernel on mac?

Tags: c, macos, assembly, kernel, nasm

I've been following the ["Mike OS Guide"](http://mikeos.berlios.de/write-your-own-os.html) to make my own kernel, and I got it working. But then I went onto the many guides on the internet for making a boot sector in `NASM` that loads a `main` function from a compiled `C` object. I have tried compiling and linking with all kinds of GCC installations:

```
x86_64-pc-linux-
arm-uclinux-elf-
arm-agb-elf-
arm-elf-
arm-apple-darwin10-
powerpc-apple-darwin10-
i686-apple-darwin10-
i586-pc-linux-
i386-elf-
```

All of them fail once I put them onto a floppy like I do with the `MikeOS` bootstrap. I've tried various tutorials on http://www.osdever.net/ like the one [here](http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/writing-a-simple-c-kernel) and I've tried http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones , but none work when trying to compile on a Mac, yet I have not tired on an actual Linux machine yet. But I was wondering how I could get a bootstrap in assembly the calls the `C` function and put them together into a working kernel file and then load the onto a floppy file then onto an ISO like in the `MikeOS` tutorial. Or should I just make the `kernel.bin` and load it with `syslinux`? Could anyone give me a tip on how to make this all work on a Mac developement environment? I have tolls via macports and homebrew so that helps. Anyone successively done this?

**EDIT**
[Here's](http://trevorrudolph.com/myfirst.asm) my bootsector so far.

I just wanna know how to jump to an `extern` function from the `C` and link it.

Comment: Boot sectors start executing in 16-bit real mode. All of the C compilers you've tried compile to 32-bit code. If you want to run code output from those compilers, your boot sector is first going to have to transition to 32-bit protected mode. Once you've done that, you only have 510 bytes, minus however many bytes it takes to switch to protected mode. You're probably going to want to write more code than will fit in that amount of space.

Comment: true, very true, what if i put BITS 32 at th beginning instead of BITS 16

Comment: Then NASM will output 32-bit code that the CPU will interpret as 16-bit code, which is most definitely not what you want.

Comment: understood, so operating systems use the space the have for a bootstrap to go from 16 bits to 32 or 64, and i dont want a 16 bit os so i would need to make the bootstrap pass off to 32 bit code? instead of a direct extern call?

Comment: No, most operating systems fill the boot sector with code to load a bigger bootloader, and then *that* bootloader will load the kernel, switch to 32-bit mode, and jump to the kernel.

Comment: I hope you realize how it is unnecessary in your current code to do many calls to `print_string`. You're doing something like `printf("a\n"); printf("b\n");` whereas you could just do `printf("a\nb\n");`.

Comment: understood, so your solution for me is to compile my c code in 16 bits or to switch to a bigger boatloder and then off to 32 bit where i can run my 32 bit code, which would require 16 bit to make that second bootloader so i need a 16 bit gcc

Comment: I'd recommend just using multiboot with GRUB. It'll handle a lot of stuff for you.

Comment: and about my code, i dont know assembly, i just know that 0Dh,0Ah, give me a new line and the ,0 was in the source when i downloaded it so i dont know what i would need for \n instead of 0Dh,0Ah,0

Comment: If you don't know assembly, then you shouldn't be trying to write a custom kernel yet. You'll *need* to know assembly to write an operating system kernel that does anything non-trivial.

Comment: and do you know any good tutorials for coding a custom kernel with my tools that will work with grub?

Comment: and i know c so im trying to get by the assembly over to c so i can work on a nice custom kernel from there you know what i mean?

Comment: Even once you're in your mostly-C kernel, you'll need to deal with assembly. For example, you need assembly to load the global descriptor table. You'll need to write assembly to handle interrupts. You'll need assembly for lots of things, and trying to squeeze by without it is simply not a good idea.

Comment: *sigh* time to learn a new leanguage that deals with bytes pretty much and hexdecimals this is all to basic :( if only i could get by with gcc -S

Comment: and this is what you were talking about in a nutshell http://wiki.osdev.org/Creating_a_64-bit_kernel#With_a_32-bit_bootstrap_in_your_kernel

Comment: Can you post the assembly code in pastebin.com or similar page? thank you.

Comment: i made a link to it on my website in the question, http://trevorrudolph.com/myfirst.asm

Comment: @Jack you can look at my source, its just the assembly part of the bootsector

Comment: @icktoofay can you make an answer saying to use a 16 bit compiler and switch over to 32 bit or 64 bit and how doing this task requires atiquit knowlage of assembly so i can set this question as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few problems with this. First of all, all the compilers you mentioned output either 32-bit or 64-bit code. That's great, but when the boot sector starts, it's running in 16-bit real mode. If you want to be able to run that 32-bit or 64-bit code, you'll need to first switch to the appropriate mode (32-bit protected mode for, well, 32-bit, and long mode for 64-bit).

Then, once you switch to the appropriate mode, you don't even have that much space for code: boot sectors are 512 bytes; two bytes are reserved for the bootable signature, and you'll need some bytes for the code that switches to the appropriate mode. If you want to be able to use partitions on that disk or maybe a FAT filesystem, take away even more usable bytes. You simply won't have enough space for all but the most trivial program.

So how do real operating systems deal with that? Real operating systems tend to use the boot sector to load a bigger bootloader from the disk. Then that bigger bootloader can load the actual kernel and switch to the appropriate mode (although that might be the responsibility of the loaded kernel — it depends).

It can be a lot of work to write a bootloader, so rather than rolling your own, **you may want to use GRUB** and have your kernel comply to the Multiboot standard. GRUB is a bootloader which will be able to load your kernel from the disk (probably in ELF format) and jump to the entry point in 32-bit protected mode. Helpful, right?

**This does not free you from learning assembly**, though: The entry point of the kernel must be assembly. Often, all it does is set up a little stack and pass the appropriate registers to a C function with the correct calling convention.

You may think that you can just copy that rather than writing it yourself, and you'd be right, but it doesn't end there. You also need assembly for (at least):

- Loading a new global descriptor table.
- Handling interrupts.
- Using non-memory-mapped I/O ports.

…and so on, not to mention that **if you have to debug, you may not have a nice debugger; instead, you'll have to look at disassemblies, register values, and memory dumps**. Even if your code is compiled from C, you'll have to know what the underlying assembly does or you won't be able to debug it.

**In summary, your main problem is not knowing assembly.** As stated before, assembly is essential for operating system development. Once you know assembly thoroughly, then you may be able to start writing an operating system.